# How to insert values in table

Tags: php, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert values in table it is saying error please tell me where i'm wrong here is my code 
its said please try again

```
   <?php
    include_once('dbconnect.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
      $cash = $_POST['cash'];

      if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl2 VALUES('',$name','$phone','$cash','date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'))"))
        echo "Successful Insertion!";
      else
        echo "Please try again";
    }


    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl2");


?>

<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
 <input type="text" name="phone"/><br />
 <input type="text" name="cash"/><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit"  value=" Enter "/>
</form>

<h1>List of companies ..</h1>
<?php
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
      echo "$row[id].$row[Name] 
                <a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a><br />";
                ?>
```

will you guide me i thought the problem is in date date

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: What error are you geting?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of [tag:php-5.5]. So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: What's your PHP version? If you are using newer PHP versions `mysql_` has been deprecated

Comment: my database not updating it run the else condition

Comment: i'm getting error in updating the database

Comment: How to _ask_ the database for what went wrong, has been discussed countless times before. Please do some proper research, instead of making us explain the same issue once again for you in "private tutoring" ...

Comment: @CBroe sir i'm doing this almost from two ho already done the search that's why asking

Comment: How can you search for two hours and not come across for example `mysql_error`?

Comment: i search for update database query , and then for how to debug the problem like that , always get the same answer which i already tried i wish i can show you the tabs which i already search

Comment: Well now you've been told, so use mysql_error, and tell us what the result is.

Comment: sorry i'm bit low in learning? where to use  mysql_error?

Comment: i was getting the error when i hit update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I can think of top my head;

1. `mysql_` has been deprecated, thus the `else` kicks in.
2. Your syntax maybe wrong for `mysql_query`?

Nonetheless, start over and start over with code that is functional and up-to-date...

Given that your connection is working properly update it to a new `mysqli` syntax, it's very simple and much more elegant:

```
$connect = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE' );
// check for an error
if ($this->_connection->connect_error)
{
    trigger_error("Connection Error: " . $this->_connection->connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Now that you are connected walk-through a new process for your code.

Start by checking like you currently are for a `submit` `$_POST` so that you can start running the script:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
    // Encode the URL when creating the variables
    $name = htmlentities( $_POST['name'] );
    $phone = htmlentities( $_POST['phone'] );
    $cash = htmlentities( $_POST['cash'] );
    $date = date( 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A' );

    // create sql
    // DO NOT INSERT VALUES STRAIGHT INTO YOUR QUERY
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl2 ( name, phone, cash, date ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )";
```

**Note:** before continuing, let me explain that you should never insert content into your query because that would throw raw user input in the mist of your code. Now, most users will never try anything fishy. But anyone could easily throw a few SQL commands inside of your inputs and `DELETE`, `SELECT`, and `UPDATE` your database content and cause numerous problems.

Here is some reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

To work around that problem, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). You can read all about it on PHP manual; and also see some real-life examples.

```
    // prepare query
    // USE PREPARED STATEMENTS
    if ($stmt = $connect->prepare( $sql ))
    {
        // bind the params
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $phone, $cash, $date);
        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // check for errors
        if ($stmt->errno)
        {
            $message = array(
                'is_error' => 'danger',
                'message' => 'Error: ' . $stmt->error
            );
        }

        // make sure at least 1 or more rows were affected
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
        {
            $message = array(
                'is_error' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Success: ' . $stmt->affected_rows . ' rows were inserted.' // value should be 1
            );
        }
        else
        {
            // if not, send warning to user
            $message = array(
                'is_error' => 'warning',
                'message' => 'Warning: ' . $stmt->affected_rows . ' rows were updated.'
            );
        }
        // close your connection
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        $message = array(
            'is_error' => 'danger',
            'message' => 'QUERY: error. Try again.'
        );
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $message = array(
        'is_error' => 'warning',
        'message' => 'There was no submission attempt. Try again.'
    );
    exit;
}
```

Notice in the code is broken down into parts where you can catch multiple errors, and it's important for debugging; it will allow you to know exactly where the code went wrong, and localize your problem to a single section of it.

Comment: This is working smoothly thank you

Comment: No problem @HuzailSpy glad the code helped